# Data from previous version of android app using SQLite

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I am using SQLite in order to build a Quiz app. I have a few questions implemented and everything is OK. Then I noticed one of them was incorrect and I put it right. When I ran the app to the emulator nothing changed. After some research I found that I had to manually erase all data from the device that was once running.

Is there any better way to solve this kind of problem than manually erasing data?

Comment: Let me guess here: You copy a pre-seeded DB from your assets into your data folder, unless there is an existing DB in your data folder. You corrected the mistake in the seeded DB and ran the app with the new DB, your data didn't change in the UI. Is this the case?

Comment: @Machinarius pretty much that is the case, yes.

Comment: Then you have to check the database version.

Comment: Then you already have your solution here. Increment the DB version and have the app run an update/migration script based on that or just wipe and replace the DB, the choice is yours. The SQLiteOpenHelper class has methods for this. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the structure of database you also need to increase the version of DB. By doing that SQLiteOpenHelper onUpgrade method will get called. You can execute any query use wish is this method but in your case simply deleting the tables and calling onCreate method would do the trick.

```
    private class MyHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "dbname.db";
    private final static int VERSION = 23; //you need to increase this


    public MyHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { 
        db.execSQL(QUERY_CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i2) {
        db.execSQL(Query_DROP_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```